# Requests returns 400 with JSON in payload, string in payload returns 200

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

Working with an API that returns nested JSON dataset after a POST request.
It expects the payload to be:

```
payload = '{"metrics":[ {"name":"Jobs.2019"}, {"name", "Jobs.2018"], "constraints": ["dimensionName": "Area", "map": {"Adams, OH":["39001"],"Allen, OH":["39003"]} }, {"dimensionName": "Industry", "map": {"Crop Production":["111000"]} } ] }'
```

Where the {"Adams, OH":["391001"]} puts a label on the FIPS code 391001 for lookup.
The issue is there are 88 counties in Ohio, and even more counties in every state of the US.

I thought I could put the counties in as counties.json

```
{
   "Adams, OH":[
      "39001"
   ],
   "Allen, OH":[
      "39003"
   ]
}
```

and set the variable in my script

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
    counties = json.load(json_file)
```

and then call my request

```
metrics = '[{"name": "Jobs.2019" }, {"name": "Jobs.2018"}, {"name": "Jobs.2017"}, {"name": "Jobs.2016"}, {"name": "Jobs.2015"}, {"name": "Jobs.2020"}, {"name": "Estab.2019" }, {"name": "Estab.2018"}, {"name": "Estab.2017"}, {"name": "Estab.2016"}, {"name": "Estab.2015"}, {"name": "Estab.2014"}, {"name": "EPW.2019"}, {"name": "EPW.2018"}, {"name": "EPW.2017"}, {"name": "EPW.2016"}, {"name": "EPW.2015"}, {"name": "EPW.2014"}]'

payload = f'{{"metrics": {metrics},  "constraints": [{{"dimensionName": "Area", "map": {counties} }}, {{"dimensionName": "Industry", "map": {{"Crop Production":["111000"]}}  ]}}'

result = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

however this returns a <400> for bad request and my payload looks like:

```
{"metrics": [{"name": "Jobs.2019" }, {"name": "Jobs.2018"}, {"name": "Jobs.2017"}, {"name": "Jobs.2016"}, {"name": "Jobs.2015"}, {"name": "Jobs.2020"}, {"name": "Estab.2019" }, {"name": "Estab.2018"}, {"name": "Estab.2017"}, {"name": "Estab.2016"}, {"name": "Estab.2015"}, {"name": "Estab.2014"}, {"name": "EPW.2019"}, {"name": "EPW.2018"}, {"name": "EPW.2017"}, {"name": "EPW.2016"}, {"name": "EPW.2015"}, {"name": "EPW.2014"}],  "constraints": [{"dimensionName": "Area", "map": {'Adams, OH': ['39001'], 'Allen, OH': ['39003']} }, {"dimensionName": "Industry", "map": {"Crop Production":["111000"]}  ]}
```

However, when I call this:

```
metrics = '[{"name": "Jobs.2019" }, {"name": "Jobs.2018"}, {"name": "Jobs.2017"}, {"name": "Jobs.2016"}, {"name": "Jobs.2015"}, {"name": "Jobs.2020"}, {"name": "Estab.2019" }, {"name": "Estab.2018"}, {"name": "Estab.2017"}, {"name": "Estab.2016"}, {"name": "Estab.2015"}, {"name": "Estab.2014"}, {"name": "EPW.2019"}, {"name": "EPW.2018"}, {"name": "EPW.2017"}, {"name": "EPW.2016"}, {"name": "EPW.2015"}, {"name": "EPW.2014"}]'

payload = '{"metrics":' + metrics + ',"constraints": [{"dimensionName": "Area", "map": {"Adams, OH":["39001"],"Allen, OH":["39003"]} }, {"dimensionName": "Industry", "map": {"Crop Production":["111000"]} } ] }'

result = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I receive a <200> with the payload looking like below:

```
{"metrics":[{"name": "Jobs.2019" }, {"name": "Jobs.2018"}, {"name": "Jobs.2017"}, {"name": "Jobs.2016"}, {"name": "Jobs.2015"}, {"name": "Jobs.2020"}, {"name": "Estab.2019" }, {"name": "Estab.2018"}, {"name": "Estab.2017"}, {"name": "Estab.2016"}, {"name": "Estab.2015"}, {"name": "Estab.2014"}, {"name": "EPW.2019"}, {"name": "EPW.2018"}, {"name": "EPW.2017"}, {"name": "EPW.2016"}, {"name": "EPW.2015"}, {"name": "EPW.2014"}],"constraints": [{"dimensionName": "Area", "map": {"Adams, OH":["39001"],"Allen, OH":["39003"]} }, {"dimensionName": "Industry", "map": {"Crop Production":["111000"]} } ] }
```

From what I'm seeing, everything is exactly the same, the interpreter spits out the JSON as single quotes (') instead of double (") but from what I recall the requests module receives the same payload.

I feel like I'm missing something blatanly dumb and obvious, but I've tried about every trick in my toolbelt at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you read the JSON file, `json.load` is returning a Python `dict`. When you then use this as an input to an `f-string`, you are just getting the Python representation of that `dict`, rather than a valid JSON object - as you've noticed, it is presented as single quotes, which are not valid in JSON - JSON is fussy about single vs. double quotes.

Instead of using `counties`, you could use `json.dumps(counties)` instead.

However, I'd recommend that you do something different. Instead of manipulating strings to create JSON objects, do that work in Python and then convert to JSON as necessary. That's what the `json` library is there to help you with!

E.g. you could do the following, which is quite a bit simpler:

```py
metrics = json.loads('[{"name": "Jobs.2019" }, {"name": "Jobs.2018"}, {"name": "Jobs.2017"}, {"name": "Jobs.2016"}, {"name": "Jobs.2015"}, {"name": "Jobs.2020"}, {"name": "Estab.2019" }, {"name": "Estab.2018"}, {"name": "Estab.2017"}, {"name": "Estab.2016"}, {"name": "Estab.2015"}, {"name": "Estab.2014"}, {"name": "EPW.2019"}, {"name": "EPW.2018"}, {"name": "EPW.2017"}, {"name": "EPW.2016"}, {"name": "EPW.2015"}, {"name": "EPW.2014"}]')

payload = {"metrics": metrics,
           "constraints": [{"dimensionName": "Area",
                            "map": counties},
                           {"dimensionName": "Industry",
                            "map": {"Crop Production": ["111000"]}}]}

result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```